# Can't precompile assets while deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I try deploy my application to heroku, and i have all the time this aborted message.

```
remote:        I, [2015-04-02T14:07:53.652063 #994]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d5672e6843462b29ddbf37fb55806c48/public/assets/active_admin/lib/popover-b154a59d4500bd0726bb70ba26dc1702.js
remote:        I, [2015-04-02T14:07:54.107466 #994]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d5672e6843462b29ddbf37fb55806c48/public/assets/active_admin/lib/table-checkbox-toggler-483727cbd1f64c5174cc4e452c842f04.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'global-reset'.
remote:        (in /tmp/build_d5672e6843462b29ddbf37fb55806c48/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-60914c887942/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.scss:3)
remote:        /tmp/build_d5672e6843462b29ddbf37fb55806c48/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-60914c887942/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.scss:3:in `global-reset'
remote:        /tmp/build_d5672e6843462b29ddbf37fb55806c48/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-60914c887942/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.scss:3
```

I tried in my initializes/assets.rb and it doesn't work for me:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.gif *.png *.ico)
config.assets.precompile << /\A(?!active_admin).*\.(js|css)\z/
```

Somebody help me?

Comment: The problem seems to be inside the stylesheet, global-reset is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Active Admin, there are several different fixes for this here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/810

It looks like the one that does the trick is @mike-marcacci's solution to add the following lines to config/environments/production.rb :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(active_admin.css active_admin/print.css rsvp.css)
config.assets.precompile += %w(active_admin.js global.js rsvp.js)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Add config.assets.enabled = false to config/application.rb